# PHP-Linking forms Using ID

Tags: php

I have a database in which I have a main form that list all personnel using this code

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("datatest", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Personnel");
echo "<TABLE BORDER=2>";
echo"<TR><TD><B>Name</B><TD><B>Number</B><TD><B>View</B><TD></TR>";
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<TR><TD>".$myrow["Surname"]." ".$myrow["First Names"]."<TD>".$myrow["Number"];
echo "<TD><a href=\"childdetails.php?EmployeeID=".$myrow["EmployeeID"]."\">View</a>";
}
echo "</TABLE>";
?>
</HTML>
```

As you can note I have a link to view details of the person but when I click on the VIEW link I get the following error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'EmployeeID' (T_STRING) in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\my portable files\dss4\childdetails.php on line 6 
The childdetails.php has the following code

```
<HTML>
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("datatest",$db);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM children; 
WHERE "EmployeeID="["$EmployeeID"],$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "Child Name: ".$myrow["ChildName"];
echo "<br>Mother: ".$myrow["Mother"];
echo "<br>Date of Birth: ".$myrow["DateOfBirth"];
?>
</HTML>
```

Since the first form to list the personnel works I believe the problem is in childdetails.php on line 6 as returned by the server but I simply don’t know how to fix it.

Note: a person can have more than one child as well as having more than one wife
Help please

Comment: You're using double quotes both inside your generated SQL statement, as well as to delimit your string.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: You have a semi-colon `;` before the `WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

You
Need
change your query something like this

```
<HTML>
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("datatest",$db);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM children WHERE EmployeeID=" . $EmployeeID, $db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "Child Name: ".$myrow["ChildName"];
echo "<br>Mother: ".$myrow["Mother"];
echo "<br>Date of Birth: ".$myrow["DateOfBirth"];
?>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Please don't teach people to avoid using prepared statements, this is a free for all sql injection.

Comment: try now with this. but remember that tell us @Jonast92 you need prepared your statements

Answer (score 0):

I would say more like.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM children WHERE EmployeeID='$EmployeeID'");
// as far $EmployeeID is actualy set before running a query
//but as comment says don't use mysql better something like this

<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'my_password', 'my_db');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
        . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM children WHERE EmployeeID=?")) {

/* bind parameters for markers */
$stmt->bind_param("s", $EmployeeID);

/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();

/* bind result variables */
$stmt->bind_result($Employee);

/* fetch value */
$stmt->fetch();

printf($Employee);

/* close statement */
$stmt->close();
}
/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Please don't teach people to avoid using prepared statements, this is a free for all sql injection.

Comment: Still probably better than what he was doing in the first place.

Comment: As you read some questions then sometimes it's just better to help them to get over some "difficulties" fast instead throwing them directly into sea of know-how.

Comment: When i used $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM children WHERE EmployeeID='$EmployeeID'") it eliminated the error but the form did not return any data thought I have data in the children table. (Children table also has EmployeeID). When I used the other code to replace the Childdetails.php i got the following error 
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\my portable files\dss4\childdetails.php on line 17 which is this  $stmt->bind_result($Employee); Where am I getting it wrong

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, your query is wrong, you're telling the sql that your script is over and that it should start executing something new. I'll show you how to do it properly here below.

Also, don't use mysql specific syntax, It's outdated and can get you into real trouble later on, especially if you decide to use sqlite or postgresql.

Also, learn to use prepared statements to avoid sql injection, you want the variables to be used as strings into a prepared query, not as a possible executing script for your sql.

Use a PDO connection, you can init one like this:

```
// Usage:   $db = connectToDatabase($dbHost, $dbName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
// Pre:     $dbHost is the database hostname, 
//          $dbName is the name of the database itself,
//          $dbUsername is the username to access the database,
//          $dbPassword is the password for the user of the database.
// Post:    $db is an PDO connection to the database, based on the input parameters.
function connectToDatabase($dbHost, $dbName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword)
{
    try
    {
         return new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName;charset=UTF-8", $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
    }
    catch(PDOException $PDOexception)
    {
        exit("<p>An error ocurred: Can't connect to database. </p><p>More preciesly: ". $PDOexception->getMessage(). "</p>");
    }
}
```

And then init the variables:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$dataBaseName = 'databaseName';
$pass = '';
```

Now you can access your database via

```
$db = connectToDatabase($host , $databaseName, $user, $pass); // You can make it be a global variable if you want to access it from somewhere else.
```

Now you should construct a query that can be used as a prepared query, that is, it accepts prepared statements so that you prepare the query and then you execute an array of variables that are to be put executed into the query, and will avoid sql injection in the meantime:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM children WHERE EmployeeID = :employeeID;"; // Construct the query, making it accept a prepared variable.
$statement = $db->prepare($query); // Prepare the query.
$statement->execute(array(':employeeID' => $EmployeeID)); // Here you insert the variable, by executing it 'into' the prepared query.
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Set the fetch mode.

while ($row = $statement->fetch())
{
    $ChildName = $row['ChildName'];
    $Mother = $row['Mother'];
    $DateOfBirth = $row['DateOfBirth'];
    echo "Child Name: $ChildName";
    echo "<br />Mother: $Mother";
    echo "<br />Date of Birth: $DateOfBirth";
}
```

You should use a similar approach to receive $EmployeeID but this should help you a lot.

By the way: remember to close your break tags with a whitespace ' ' and a forwardslash like I showed you.

Comment: Well thanks. i really would not want sql injection. Nowe the problem is that i am a\ newbie to php and sql (i am infact migrating my MS Access db to sql and with self teaching its not easy. I have said this so you will understand my question. The code you have given me seems it need to be in 3 separate php files? Right?

Comment: It doesn't have to, It's optional :) Also, It's better to spend a litte more time to learn the practices that are most used and are safest and in the end, simplest.

Comment: Actually what i meant was that id not want someone to sql inject my db, so i need to switch to your option. i first thought that if you prevent sql injection in the login script then you are fine, but i see that it is not the case.